# running total in highcharts

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

So I am able to populate an array with values in json format in highcharts by writing the following code:

```
var processed_json = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  processed_json.push({
    x: data[i].duration,
    y: data[i].count
  });
}
```

My problem lies with trying to create a running total of duration on the x-axis.
I have thought about creating a second array to loop over the first and to then add the values, but how do I add the values in the second array, if I refer to the values by their title '.duration' in the first?

I need to populate an array with cumulative sum values, to then plot on the x axis. I hope this makes sense?

Does their exist an easier way to solve my issue?

I am quite new to javascript and highcharts, so apologies if there is an easier way to solve this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are already looping. Just create a total variable outside it and use `total += data[i].duration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I understood what you are trying to achieve. You must have somewhere declared variable with JSON containing options for generating Highcharts chart. I assume that it's name is `highchartsOptions`.

```
highchartsOptions.xAxis.categories = [];
var processed_json = new Array(),
    durationSum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  processed_json.push({
    x: data[i].duration,
    y: data[i].count
  });
  durationSum += data[i].duration;
  highchartsOptions.xAxis.categories.push(durationSum);
}
```

This shall add categories axis. And every category with index `i` will be sum of all data duration preceeding.

Comment: And BTW. You might want to rename your "something_json" array variable to somethig that does not suggest that it is json (since it's and array of JSONs)